# child-parent soql query custom object

Tags: apex, trigger

I have Contact as parent object & dealer_cart as child object.
There is a lookup relationship defined on child object i.e dealer_cart

Comment: Hi Hafiza, welcome to stackexchange. You might want to add some more details to your question, because the way it is described right now is still quite unclear what kind of help you're looking for. Here's some hints: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! I've linked a question that, I believe, answers your question. If not, please [edit] your question and provide more information, and we'll be happy to help you.

Comment: @GuyClairbois Just in case you don't already know, there are some quick links that we can use in comments like `[ask]`, `[tour]`, and `[edit]` instead of needing to find/type the full url.